# Xamarin.IOS creating an actionSheetDatePicker

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

This code

```
actionSheetDatePicker = new ActionSheetDatePicker (this.View);
```

no longer works on the xamarin now. How would I create a datePicker upon a click of a button?

Answer (score 0):

`ActionSheetDatePicker` is deprecated in iOS 8, you can find alternate implementation in this [blog post here](http://sharpmobilecode.com/a-replacement-for-actionsheet-date-picker/) and sample code [here](https://github.com/SharpMobileCode/ModalPickerViewController)